# I need to webscrape content that is not showed in the view-source: of browser

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm trying to **webscrape** a page that not return content from a dynamic content into a DIV.

The Dynamic content is not loaded by request library.

I saw what is the problem on the topic below, but i need know if i have other way to get this content.

[How is it possible for the page source not to show what is on the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689256/how-is-it-possible-for-the-page-source-not-to-show-what-is-on-the-page)

[IMAGE Using view-source: in the browser does not have content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzK0v.png)

[IMAGE SHOWING Inspecting Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cm23Z.png)

Answer (score 1):

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-scraping-with-node-js-daa2027dcd3/

I found a source thats explain about it, the solution was use Puppeteer Library

Puppeteer can execute java script from sites taking that dynamic content.

And then you can use cheerio to separate your tag.